# What is the correct expression for a web job in Azure to run every 2 hours?

Tags: php, azure, cron, azure-webjobs

I set my web job (cron job) on Azure to run every 2 hours like this

```
0 * */2 * * *
```

However it runs every minute, for a reason I don't know why.

What is the correct expression for a web job in Azure to run every 2 hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
0 0 */2 * * *
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs